# What vim theme is this?

Tags: vim

I just ssh'd into a machine and I like the vim theme a lot. Does anyone know it's name? Here are a few screen shots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You should be able to see it in `.vimrc`.

Comment: No .vimrc exists. It's using the system defaults I guess.

Comment: That should be `/etc/vim/vimrc` IIRC

Comment: With Vim 8: `:filter /colors/ scriptnames` should give you the most likely candidates.

Answer (score 3):

There should be a variable `g:colors_name` that is set to the same name of the colour scheme.

To found out my color scheme I did this:

> step1 ==> open some file via **vim** `vim somefile.txt`
>
> step2 ==> press `ESC`
>
> step3 ==> press `shift` + `:`
>
> step4 ==> type `echo g:colors_name` (for Vim 8.0 or higher) or type`colo` (for recent versions) and press `enter`

I got `elflord`

If you get `default` output so you are using a malformed colour scheme and there's not a lot you can do about it other than manually switching themes until you recognise it. You can find a lot of color vim schemes here ==> [color_schemes](http://vimcolors.com/)

It is needed to mention that my version of vim is **VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0**

The idea of this answer was taken from this answer on StackOverflow ==>[vim_color_scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419624/how-to-tell-which-colorscheme-a-vim-session-currently-uses)

Comment: Fails for me with vim 7.4 : `E121: Undefined variable: g:colors_name
E15: Invalid expression: g:colors_name
`

Comment: schaiba, I have extended my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I get Schaiba's error when I try the first method, and I get ""E471: Argument required" when I try the second method. 

vim version 7.2 (2008, Aug 9, includes patches: 1-330)

Comment: Anyway `.vimrc` should be present. Open some file in `vim` and run `:edit $MYVIMRC` to see your `.vimrc` settings and its location.
When `edit` window opens add this line to it ==> `syntax on`.